# Trouble allowing other users to see user uploaded images on Godot 4.2

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

Sorry if this has a really obvious fix but I'm new to godot and have been stuck on this a while. I am working on a game in godot 4.2 using rpc and local host for multiplayer and file dialog for image upload. I have gotten images to successfully upload but it won't show on other players' clients.

Here is some of the relevant snippets of my code:

```
# Individual player joining game
@rpc("any_peer", "call_local")
func send_player_information(name_entry):
    
    GameManager.Players.append({
        "name": name_entry, 
        "score": 0,
        "prompt": "",
        "image": PackedByteArray(),
    })
```

```
func _on_file_dialog_file_selected(path):
    var image = Image.load_from_file(path)
    var texture = ImageTexture.create_from_image(image)
    
    # Saving file paths to a file
    #var file = FileAccess.open("res://photo-paths.txt", FileAccess.WRITE)
    #file.store_string(path)
    
    var raw_data = image.save_png_to_buffer()
    
    image = Image.new()
    var err = image.load_png_from_buffer(raw_data)
    if err != OK:
        printerr("Image loading error: " + str(err))
        return
    texture = ImageTexture.create_from_image(image)
    $ImageUploadScene/Image.texture = texture
    
    
    imagesUploaded += 1
    
    rpc("on_image_uploaded", player_id, raw_data)
    
    
    # Checking if the images uploaded equals the number of players in the game
    
    players = GameManager.Players.size()
    if imagesUploaded >= players:
        
        $ImageUploadScene.hide()
        $PresentationScene.show()
        rpc("presentation")


# Upload an image to the player function
@rpc("any_peer", "call_local")
func on_image_uploaded(id: int, image_base64: String):
    GameManager.Players[id].image = image_base64


@rpc("any_peer", "call_local")
func presentation():
    
    var i = 0
    players = GameManager.Players.size()
    
    while (i < players):
        
        $PresentationScene/Prompt.text = GameManager.Players[i].prompt
        $PresentationScene/Name.text = GameManager.Players[i].name
        
        
        # Load in the image
        rpc("update_player_image_display", i)
        
        
        # Start timer
        $PresentationScene/Timer.start(25.0)
        await $PresentationScene/Timer.timeout
        
        i += 1
    
    $PresentationScene.hide()
    $VotingScene.show()
    rpc("voting")


@rpc("any_peer", "call_local")
func update_player_image_display(i):
    # Load in the image
    var image = Image.new()
    var raw_data = GameManager.Players[i].image
    var err = image.load_png_from_buffer(raw_data)
    if err != OK:
        printerr("Image loading error: " + str(err))
        return
    var texture = ImageTexture.create_from_image(image)
    
    $PresentationScene/Image.texture = texture
```

Here is the [full code](https://github.com/utk-cs340-fall23/SchoolSubjectSmackdown/blob/main/Artful_Deceptions/main.gd)

What I have been mainly trying to do is pass the image as base64 but I found it difficult to find godot 4 notation that works

Would appreciate any help you could give. Thank you

Comment: Your link for the full code is broken

Comment: Have you checked for errors?